# how to set each row to pass its values to servlet - whatever input I click, I have always first row

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Why I can only count value for first row, though Jsp displays every row with correct values.
It always pass first row of data to the Servlet. If I choose first row it works, but if I choose any other it takes values of first row and program collapse due to empty string.

```
 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws 
 ServletException, IOException {


    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();

    String currency = request.getParameter("currency");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    float rates = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("rates"));
    float amount =  
Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("amount"));;

    float euro = amount * rates;
    printWriter.append(String.valueOf(id)).append(" : ");
    printWriter.append(currency).append(" - ");
    printWriter.append("rate : ").append(String.valueOf(rates));
    printWriter.append(" ---> You have got 
").append(String.valueOf(euro)).append(" 
    Euros");

 }

<form action="/exchangeServlet" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Currency</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="tempValue" items="${kalkulatorList}" 
varStatus="counter">
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${tempValue.id}">
        <td><input type="hidden" name="currency" 
value="${tempValue.currency}">${tempValue.currency}</td>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="rates" 
value="${tempValue.rates}">${tempValue.rates}</td>

        <td><input type="number" name="amount"  placeholder="enter 
amount"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Exchange"></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</form>
```

JSP view after loaded data from a xml file:

```
<tr>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="currency" 
value="USD">USD</td>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="rates" 
value="1.0067">1.0067</td>

        <td><input type="number" name="amount"  value="0.0" 
placeholder="enter amount"/></td>
        <td><a href="/exchangeServlet? 
command=Exchange&currencyId=2">Exchange</a></td>


    </tr>


    
    <tr>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="currency" 
value="JPY">JPY</td>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="rates" 
value="138.02">138.02</td>

        <td><input type="number" name="amount"  value="0.0"  
placeholder="enter amount"/></td>
        <td><a href="/exchangeServlet? 
command=Exchange&currencyId=3">Exchange</a></td>


    </tr>


    
    <tr>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="currency" 
value="BGN">BGN</td>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="rates" 
value="1.9558">1.9558</td>

        <td><input type="number" name="amount"  value="0.0" 
placeholder="enter amount"/></td>
        <td><a href="/exchangeServlet? 
command=Exchange&currencyId=4">Exchange</a></td>


    </tr>
```

Comment: From the example you show, the form that triggers the servlet only has one row of data. It looks like 'working as designed'.

Comment: Actually it parse data from xml fileand creates multiple rows. That how it looks in jsp view after loaded from a file:

Comment: I updated post with a view

Comment: Actually I have figured it out, it works.